# What is different between "fear" and "afraid of"?

Tags: expressions

I wrote that "I am afraid of freedom".
A proofreader changed it to 'fear freedom'
I thought both are similar meanings like
the feeling of being in danger.

Comment: I assume you mean "I *am afraid of* freedom" vs. "I *fear* freedom".

Comment: This is more of an issue of style than grammar. 'Fear' can be seen as a stronger emotion; it carries connotations of terror much more than 'afraid' does. Also, 'afraid' suggests timidness, which is not so apparent with 'fear'. The shortening of the sentence also makes the statement 'stand out' more, if you know what I mean, which may be the effect the proofreader is trying to achieve. Just my two-cents worth.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your sentence

> I *am afraid of* freedom.

is grammatically correct, understandable, and useable.

> I *fear* freedom.

is also correct, understandable, and useable.

Both mean you are concerned about how freedom might effect you.

> ***Fear*** is what you feel when you ***are afraid of*** something.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are correct. **Fear** is nothing but a *verb,* and **afraid** is an *adjective*. To make the sentence concise, your proofreader may have applied this change